# Find cdf of sum using the convolution formula

Tags: probability

> Given: a random vector $(X,Y)$ with the density $f_{XY}(x,y)=\tfrac{1}{4}$ on the triangle $T_1$ with vertices $$(0,-1),(0,0),(1,0)$$ and density $f_{XY}(x,y)=\tfrac{21}{53}xy$
>   on the trapezoid $T_2$ with vertices $$(1,0),(0,1),(3,1),(3,0).$$
>
> Find the cdf of $Z=X+Y$.

Any suggestions on how to apply the convolution formula (provided by S.Ross's book)?

$$F_{X+Y}(a)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_X(a-y)f_Y(y)dy $$

Answer (score 2):

Since you are given  only the pdfs, you can use this convolution formula..$$f_{_{X+Y}}(s)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty f_{_{X,Y}}(s-y,y)\ dy$$
Then you can divide the range of $Y$ into two parts and apply the limits appropriately.

Comment: Hi @Querty, I'm a little bit confused. Is this for $T_1$ correct?

$f_{_{X+Y}}(s)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty f_{_{X,Y}}(s-y,y)\ dy = f_{_{X+Y}}(s)=\int\limits_{-1}^{x-1} f_{_{X,Y}}(s-y,y)\ dy = f_{_{X+Y}}(s)=\int\limits_{-1}^{x-1} \frac{1}{4}\ dy$